# Malformed Lambda proxy response when access lambda REST

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I use `Javascript` to create simple function that would be deployed on AWS Lambda and used as REST.

It supposed to generate random names but for now I use hardcoded value.

```
// NamingService.js
class NamingService {
    generateName() {
        return 'generated-name'
    }
}

module.exports = NamingService;
```

In this file I handle requests

```
const NamingService = require('./NamingService');

const responses = {
    success: (data={}) => {
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    },
    error: (error) => {
        return {
            "statusCode": error.code || 500,
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify(error)
        }
    }
};

module.exports = {
    generateName: (event, context, callback) => {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        const namingService = new NamingService();
        namingService.generateName()
            .then(name => {
                callback(null, responses.success(name))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                callback(null, responses.error(error))
            })
    }
};
```

I use `serverless` to deploy lambda function

```
service: naming-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 30

functions:
  generateName:
    handler: lambdaHandlers.generateName
    events:
      - http:
          path: jester/name/generate
          method: get
          cors:
            origins:
              - '*'
```

After `serverless deploy` it shows me the response

```
region: eu-west-1
stack: naming-service-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  GET - https://endpoint/jester/name/generate
functions:
  generateName: naming-service-dev-generateName
```

But when I try to run it (using test on API gateway) I get this error

```
Fri May 11 21:37:19 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "generated-name"
Fri May 11 21:37:19 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response headers: {Content-Length=16, Date=Fri, 11 May 2018 21:37:19 GMT;sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Fri May 11 21:37:19 UTC 2018 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Fri May 11 21:37:19 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 502
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Suspicious: header values are strings, so your boolean `true` seems like a type mismatch.  I'd suggest a string value, `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it seems it cannot find `namingService.generateName(...).then` during execution (looked at logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `generateName` handler. I shouldn't have used `then` on method `generateName`

```
generateName: (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const namingService = new NamingService();
    const generatedName = namingService.generateName();
    callback(null, responses.success(generatedName));
}
```